# PHP : Execute a program in background multiple times, once

Tags: php, background, exec

I have written a program with " C ", and I would like to execute it with php, I tried to use the function php_exec, but It doesn't work. To be more specific in my problem I will tell you some details. This program is used to make downloads faster, in brief, the users will enter to a webpage, a put their direct links, then submit their links to have a direct link from my server, the problem here is that " How can I can let the user use it, is there any equivalent to php_exec ? " Because I think that php_exec does not work if many users send their links in the same time, also I would like to know, can this harm my server ?
Thank you !

Answer (score 3):

You probably do not want to use `exec` in that situation since it waits until the executed program is finished which blocks the complete script.

The [PHP Documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) tells you the following:

> **Note:** If a program is started with this function, in order for it to continue running in the background, the output of the program must be redirected to a file or another output stream. Failing to do so will cause PHP to hang until the execution of the program ends.

However, you probably want to add the links to a queue (maybe a database) and execute a cron job every now and then which then downloads the files which are stored in the queue.

There is also another similar question with an [excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45966/246051).

Answer (score 1):

```
// Start your 'downloader'
$handle = popen('/path/to/executable 2>&1', 'r');
// While it's generating output, print it to the screen
while (!feof($handle)){
    echo fread($handle, 2096);
}
// Close the process handle
pclose($handle);
```

This *will* allow multiple users to use it at the same time. Each PHP process will fork it's own copy of `/path/to/executable`, and will enable flushing of the output of the background process to the users screen.